# multiple count(distinct)

Tags: sql, t-sql, count, distinct, visual-foxpro

I get an error unless I remove one of the `count(distinct ...)`. Can someone tell me why and how to fix it?
I'm in vfp. `iif([condition],[if true],[else])` is equivalent to `case when`

```
SELECT * FROM dpgift where !nocalc AND rectype = "G" AND sol = "EM112" INTO CURSOR cGift
    SELECT
        list_code,
        count(distinct iif(language != 'F' AND renew = '0'  AND type =  'IN',donor,0)) as d_Count_E_New_Indiv,
        count(distinct iif(language = 'F' AND renew = '0'   AND type =  'IN',donor,0)) as d_Count_F_New_Indiv /*it works if i remove this*/
    FROM cGift gift
        LEFT JOIN
                (select didnumb, language, type from dp) d
            on cast(gift.donor as i) = cast(d.didnumb as i)
    GROUP BY list_code
    ORDER by list_code
```

edit:
apparently, you can't use multiple distinct commands on the same level. Any way around this?

Comment: SQL: Distinct is invalid

Comment: First thing I would consider is that cursor...why are you using it, there is ALWAYS a better way than a cursor.  

With that said...For counting distinct my preference is to build a select statement that obtains the ID you wish to join it on + the count you are looking for (use group by to get that distinct) and then join that as a subquery back to your table.  If you can give the schema and what counts as a 'distinct' row, I can build an answer for you.

Comment: @Twelfth, welcome to VFox, where cursors are used extensively and to good effect. What's worse is that the OP has actually made this query look pretty... he could easily have stopped writing every key word at four characters... *sigh* I hate VFox.

Comment: ^yup, i'm hating it too. I went from learning oracle/java/c# to an internship using vfp. When i realized i could use sql directly i was ecstatic, but apparently it has limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VFP does NOT support two "DISTINCT" clauses in the same query... PERIOD...  I've even tested on a simple table of my own, DIRECTLY from within VFP such as

```
select count( distinct Col1 ) as Cnt1, count( distinct col2 ) as Cnt2 from MyTable
```

causes a crash.  I don't know why you are trying to do DISTINCT as you are just testing a condition... I more accurately appears you just want a COUNT of entries per each category of criteria instead of actually DISTINCT

Because you are not "alias.field" referencing your columns in your query, I don't know which column is the basis of what.  However, to help handle your DISTINCT, and it appears you are running from WITHIN a VFP app as you are using the "INTO CURSOR" clause (which would not be associated with any OleDB .net development), I would pre-query and group those criteria, something like...

```
select list_code,
       donor,
       max( iif( language != 'F' and renew = '0' and type = 'IN', 1, 0 )) as EQualified,
       max( iif( language  = 'F' and renew = '0' and type = 'IN', 1, 0 )) as FQualified
   from
      list_code
   group by
      list_code,
      donor
   into 
      cursor cGroupedByDonor
```

so the above will ONLY get a count of 1 per donor per list code, no matter how many records that qualify.  In addition, if one record as an "F" and another does NOT, then you'll have a value of 1 in EACH of the columns...  Then you can do something like...

```
select
      list_code,
      sum( EQualified ) as DistEQualified,
      sum( FQualified ) as DistFQualified
   from
      cGroupedByDonor
   group by
      list_code
   into
      cursor cDistinctByListCode
```

then run from that...

Answer (score 1):

You can try using either another derived table or two to do the calculations you need, or using projections (queries in the field list). Without seeing the schema, it's hard to know which one will work for you.

Comment: Yeah - you may have to rethink what you need here.  You can't have two distincts in a query like that, you'll have to drop to another subquery  or rethink.

Comment: yeah, i'm reworking everything. Still don't understand why two distincts don't work, I'm pretty sure they work on other platforms.